# Upload Video on Daily Motion through android Api

Tags: android, video, upload

How can i add feature to upload captured video through my Android app using daily motion api?
any idea

Comment: i didnt get any thing... how can i do....

Comment: Do you want to upload video on server ?

Comment: Yes i want to upload video on Daily Motion Server

Comment: GO through there [DOCUMENTATION](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/getting-started.html#publishing-videos) It is well explained

Comment: But i am not getting DailyMotion Android API

Comment: i means any daily motion jar file for android for uploading.. In daily motion documention provided Daily motion sdk are JS sdk, Php Sdk and Obj-c Sdk... have a look [link](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/sdk.html#sdk)